# Bypassing group policy

Tags: group-policy

I'm trying to prevent users from pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>DEL</kbd> while their accounts are logging in to our domain (ie. while the system is creating the user profile, applying group policies, etc.).

Due to long log in times, our users have found a way to reduce that time by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>DEL</kbd> while logging in. While this does reduce their log in time by allowing them into the system straight away, certain group policies don't apply.

I'm wondering if anyone else has had this issue at the sites they manage and/or if they've found a "patch" for it.

Comment: how are they bypassing it? are they starting taskmgr? then you could just disable latter for them

Comment: Which policies don;t apply in this situation?

Comment: @DanielNachtrub we've disabled task manager for our users, they seem to press CTRL ALT DEL during login and then press the escape key right after the menu has appeared on screen.

Comment: @BlueCompute from my research it looks like policies relating to printer connections are not applying.

Comment: How bizarre.  Are these group policy preference items?   Have you tried disabling asynchronous group policy processing with the 'Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon' policy setting?

Comment: No they are policy items (through Computer Config > Policies > Windows Settings > Printer Connections).
Asynchronous group policy processing hasn't been configured so I believe the the default behavior is that the computer will always apply policies before logging the users on. I will try testing it with that policy enabled.

Comment: Default is asynchronous 'fast logon optimization' https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/jj573586.aspx

Comment: I didn't know that something like this was possible...wtf.